# Jquery toggle with link inside the toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() { 
        $('#toggle1').click(function() { 
            $('.toggle1').toggle();
            return false;
        });
    }); 
</script> 

<a href="#" id="toggle1" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;">Text Before <a href="http://www.google.com">link</a> Text After</a><br /><br />

<div class="toggle1" style="display:none;">More Text Here</div>
```

The problem with this is that it is not valid HTML and even though the toggle1 link and the link inside toggle1 link both work, and the "Text Before" is clickable, the "Text After" is not clickable and does not toggle.

Have you any suggestions how to fix it so that "Text After" is also clickable so that toggle would work?

Thank you all!

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Comment: You need to make the HTML valid. Link inside another link won't work.

Comment: I realize that the link inside another link won't work. So, how  would one make "Text After" clickable, so that toggle would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser will automatically inject a closing tag into you code to make it valid. That's why you are not able to click on the 'text after'. Please inspect through some element inspectors, then you can understand what is happening.

See how your code was rendered in browser
[image]

So why cant you make it like this?

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="toggler" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;">Text Before</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">link</a>
<a href="#" class="toggler" style="text-decoration:none;color:black;">Text After</a><br /><br />

<div class="toggle1" style="display:none;">More Text Here</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function() { 
    $('.toggler').click(function() { 
        $('.toggle1').toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: this is just re-stating the problem, rather than offering a solution.

Comment: thank you. it took me a while to do this for all links programmatically.